# after_setup_theme is called three times

Tags: themes, hooks

Trying to find an issue with my theme that is not related with this question, I've started the debugger and enabled a breakpoint to the first line of a function hooked to `after_setup_theme`.

Here I've realized that the function is called three times, before the page is rendered.

Is that normal?
Isn't this action supposed to be called only one time?

Here's an excerpt of the functions.php (`after_setup_theme` is the only hook in functions.php):

```
function get_theme_text_domain()
{
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    return $theme->get('TextDomain');
}

//This is the function that is called 3 times when opening any page of the site
function tamtando_theme_setup()
{
    load_textdomain(get_theme_text_domain(), get_template_directory() . '/languages');
    //[...]
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'tamtando_theme_setup');
```

To clarify, checking the value of $wp_filter['after_setup_theme'], I've found 2 hooks: one is from my theme, the other, from the "Event Organiser" plugin, calling a different function (I wonder why the developer is using this hook, but this doesn't relate to this issue).

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Do you have any wp-cron jobs queued for processing? WordPress can make calls back to itself to process things, and this can cause the whole page to load again, including the hooks.

Comment: No, the wp-cron is disabled in the wp-config.

Comment: @AndreaSciamanna - EO uses that hook to define a constant pointing to the plug-in's directory. It uses `after_setup_theme` - because someone complained that their theme set up symlinks and they weren't able to over-ride the value assigned to the constant from their theme. I maintain that theme's shouldn't be doing that (a plug-ins job) but anyhow - that's what that [function is doing](https://github.com/stephenharris/Event-Organiser/blob/2.1.5/event-organiser.php#L47) :).

Comment: Good to know @Stephen :)

Answer (score 2):

Hooks and filters can have several Actions attached. Hence the `$priority` argument. In short: It's just a big multi dimensional array where the key is the hook/filter name and the values are the attached callbacks plus their priority.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but this is the "after_setup_theme" and as far as I can see, in my theme, this actions is hooked only once. Unless some plugin hooks to my function (but how it could know the function name, considering that it has a very unique name?), to me it seems that WP itself is executing this action 3 times and, again, I wonder if this is normal.

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['after_setup_theme'] );` for more info.

Comment: See my last edit (the last sentences).

Answer (score 1):

`after_setup_theme` action should be called only once. It's called on line 294 of `wp-settings.php` file directly (not inside any function). So I don't see how/why it could be called 3 times.

The only reason I can think of to this situation (debugger stopping on this function) is that `wp_cron` is processing some scheduled events. I'm not sure if it will call this action then, but it definitely will include `wp-settings.php` file and I don't see any if statements that will disable this action when it's wp_cron, so it's possible.

Remember that WordPress has some events scheduled even when you don't schedule them manually.

You should also check What happens when you add `echo 'bla';` in your `after_setup_theme` callback? Will it be echoed 3 times? Maybe it's only some debugger issue?

Comment: I've already stated the wp-cron is disabled. By the way, even supposing that is enabled, after_setup_theme is called ALWAYS 3 times, when loading a page.
If wp-cron would be the issue, the function would be called continuously (the debugger is always enabled), instead, the 3 times it's a constant.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see info about wp-cron is disabled. What happens when you add `echo 'bla';` in your `after_setup_theme` callback? Will it be echoed 3 times? Maybe it's only some debugger issue?

Comment: Oh, well... it appears you're right. 
I see only one echo.

Comment: OK. I would also check it with some logging into file solution. Maybe there are some redirects or output is buffered and cleaned, so you see it only once.

Comment: I really think it's a debugger issue. If you post your comment as answer, I'll mark it as answered.